# Adding Item to Dictionary is breaking foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary, foreach, ui-automation

I'm trying to loop through a collection of items and add their properties to a Dictionary, though for some reason its not finishing the loop.

My code:

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> elementList = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>(); 
public void AddElementList(AutomationElementCollection collection)
{

    foreach (AutomationElement ele in collection)
    {
        elementList.Add(ele.Cached.Name, new Tuple<string, string>(ele.Cached.LocalizedControlType.ToString(), ele.Cached.AutomationId.ToString()));
        i++;

    }
    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
}
```

Its not getting to the MessageBox.Show at all. There is usually around 52 items, it loops through 8 then quits.

Comment: catch or break on Exceptions in the debugger, and you'll probably see where you've gone wrong. Perhaps a duplicate key attempted to insert.

Comment: My best guess is `ele.Cached.Name` is duplicated, throwing an exception.

Comment: Yup totally right, I can't believe I didn't think about that!

Comment: Since your `Tuple` is only holding two values, why not use a `KeyValuePair`?  It will have far better support by .Net than the `Tuple`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You say that it goes through 8 times then stops. It may be the case that when you call [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the dictionary that it throws an [ArgumentException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx) because An element with the same key already exists in the Dictionary.

This happens because when you go to look up a value in a dictionary, that it looks for that key, of cause if there were two of the same key, you wouldn't know which value to return.